# What are Other Galaxies made of? Are they different than our own?

Tags: stars

Does NASA use a spectrograph to see what other Galaxies are made of?
If they do has NASA discovered other Galaxies that are made of different Elements than our own?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the astronomy stack.ecchange

Comment: Hi @john there are almost [200 Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) and it's sometimes hard to judge where to ask a question. Questions about observational astronomy are best asked and answered in [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) rather than here in Space Exploration. I think your question will be closed as off-topic. Don't worry, it happens to all of us. While most questions about NASA end up here, those about using NASA telescopes like Hubble to learn about galaxies would to in Astronomy SE instead.

Comment: The quickest way to proceed is for you to 1) check Astronomy SE to make sure your exact question hasn't been asked already, 2) if not, post your question there, 3) delete it here since it is discouraged to ask the same question in multiple sites. Good luck and *Welcome to Space!